# Execute GH action on PR and push to branch

Tags: github-actions

I want the GH action to run when I create pr to master OR push to any other branch.
When I create a new pr, the GH action executed twice, probably something with my config.

[image]

Here is the relevant part of the workflow

```
on:
  push:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [topic on GitHub](https://github.com/gleam-lang/gleam/issues/309) you will find there reference to [Skip Duplicate Actions](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/skip-duplicate-actions)

> If you work with feature branches, then you might see lots of duplicate workflow-runs. For example, duplicate workflow-runs can happen if a workflow runs on a feature branch, but then the workflow is repeated right after merging the feature branch. skip-duplicate-actions allows to prevent such runs.
>
> - Full traceability: After clean merges, you will see a message like Skip execution because the exact same files have been successfully checked in <previous_run_URL>.
> - Fully configurable: By default, manual triggers and cron will never be skipped.
> - Flexible Git usage: skip-duplicate-actions does not care whether you use fast-forward-merges, rebase-merges or squash-merges. However, if a merge yields a result that is different from the source branch, then the resulting workflow-run will not be skipped. This is commonly the case if you merge "outdated branches".

You need to set `concurrent_skipping` which takes one of the following values `never`, `same_content`, `outdated_runs`, `always`.

Comment: I saw this answer, in my opinion, I should not use actions for basic things gh actions should provide by default.

Comment: You are correct. But, are you sure if GitHub Actions provides this? If not what other options you have. I fully agree with you, because it will make workflow more complex, but sometime we are where we are.